# using MPI: What on earth is "execvp error on file" error?

Tags: mpi

I am using my own laptop locally with win 10 system and intel parallel studio .

After I compiled my mpi code with mpiifort and run it with mpiexec for the first time. It warns me to input account and password, like below

[image]

I am sure I put in the correct password. But it just didn't work. What does "execvp error" mean? I never encountered this problem before on my old win8 system. I just installed this new win10 system on my laptop, everything is new. **Could somebody please help me instead of making close vote without any comment?** At least, say something

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47472153/mpi-mpirun-execvp-error-no-such-file-or-directory?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

`execvp error on file` is the error from doing [`execvp` system call](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html). It is variant of `exec` system call used to start programs. In your case the `mpiexec` program tries to start the `mpi-learning-pack.exe` file on the target hosts (according to settings, probably some environment settings). This error says that it can't start your program on target hosts, because either it is not executable file, or cannot be found (not copied to target hosts or have no full path).

`mpiexec` does not copy file to targets, you should copy it to every target hosts.

You can also check if it executable by manually starting it on target host:  just login to target host and type `mpi-learning-pack.exe` without mpiexec; 
program may not start if there are no any of required library on target.

Or your account has no enough privileges like https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-clusters-and-hpc-technology/topic/607844 https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-clusters-and-hpc-technology/topic/624054

Or you just should use relative (`mpiexec [options] .\mpi-learning-pack.exe`) or full path (`mpiexec [options] e:\w\work\fortran\_test_and_learning\mpi-learning-pack.exe`)  of target executable like in https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-clusters-and-hpc-technology/topic/624054

Comment: Thank you so much, osgx. But problem still can not solved. Running `mpi-learning-pack.exe` is fine without problem. And I also tried use  full path, it gives the same error. I am an intel mpi user for several years, never seen such a problem. It seems like a problem of incorrect password. But I have reboot my laptop several times and I am sure I input the correct password. Also my account is administration, my cmd is open with administration privilege. Is there something different between win 8 and win 10's privilege system?

Comment: The intel forum link you provide seems just my case, But I just don't understand what they say, where should I look at? I am not on a sever, it is just a local computer

Comment: Use linux for MPI. Or try  "-localonly" option of intel mpi - as said https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-clusters-and-hpc-technology/topic/706868. If it will not help, post debug output as was required in this link

Comment: Hi, osgx, thank you. But ·-localonly` doesn't work. I finally solve this by create a new account. In this new account, everything is OK.  I still have no idea what is wrong with my previous account. But one thing to note is that in new account, I also encountered this error message at first. Then, I found this is related to Total commander I use. I set total commander(TC) with admin privilege, and the cmd open within TC is also admin, somehow it just didn't work for mpiexec. After I remove the admin privilege of TC, things works. But in my old account, it just didn't work in any way.