# MPI mpirun execvp error: no such file or directory

Tags: mpi

I'm trying to run a c++ code (BCparallel.cpp) using MPI; compiling the code with:

```
 mpic++ BCparallel.cpp -o BCparallel
```

is well succeed, but when I pass the line

```
 mpiexec -np 4 BCparallel file.txt
```

It returns

```
[proxy:0:0@lps-Inspiron-5537] HYDU_create_process 
(utils/launch/launch.c:75): execvp error on file BCparallel (No such 
file or directory)
[proxy:0:0@lps-Inspiron-5537] HYDU_create_process 
(utils/launch/launch.c:75): execvp error on file BCparallel (No such 
file or directory)
[proxy:0:0@lps-Inspiron-5537] HYDU_create_process 
(utils/launch/launch.c:75): execvp error on file BCparallel (No such 
file or directory)
[proxy:0:0@lps-Inspiron-5537] HYDU_create_process 
(utils/launch/launch.c:75): execvp error on file BCparallel (No such 
file or directory)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is not C++ question.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The program is not in your `$PATH` and you have not specified the path where it exists.  Try this:

```
mpiexec -np 4 ./BCparallel file.txt
```

This is the same as for any other program, which if it is not in `$PATH` must be qualified with a path.  This protects you from accidentally running a program called `ls` (for example) in your current directory.

Comment: I did this but, I still get the same error. [proxy:0:0@MyUbuntu] HYDU_create_process (/home/nikhil/Downloads/libraries/mpich-3.2.1/src/pm/hydra/utils/launch/launch.c:75): execvp error on file ./HelloWorld.out (Permission denied)

Comment: @Nikhil: Your error is different (Permission denied).  You might want to post a new question if you can't figure it out.  But it might just be you need to say `chmod +x ./HelloWorld.out` first.

Comment: @JohnZwinck if I have multiple instances of the program (for ex.: different Python installs/environments) it can be the case?

Comment: @RicardoBarrosLourenço: I don't understand your question.